# Laravel access to files from another PC / Mapped Network Drive

Tags: laravel, laravel-facade, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem

Sorry i'm still new to this.
I would like to access/read files from another PC within the same network using Laravel. I can access the files over mapped network drive from my PC.

I have try to access through Laravel Storage disk but still failed for drive over network.
Here is my filesystems.php

```
    'example1' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => 'W:/',
    ],
    'example2' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => '10.1.101.11/reports',
    ],
```

[image]

is there any correct way to do this? thanks

Comment: `'root' => '10.1.101.11/reports'` and using `local` as driver? you will have better chance if you **mount/map** that network drive to drive `Z:` or something and use that instead of IP. are you using [windows](https://superuser.com/a/232990), mac, or linux? depending on the OS, it need different command(s) to mount network drives.

Comment: or make a `symlink` in storage folder.

Comment: Well, i  guess that's not correct way too. What is the possible driver for the network drive? .Im using Windows and as stated i already mapped the drive to `W:`.

Comment: sysmlink ?  . i got try to explore that. thanks

Comment: still havent find out the solution ~

Comment: thats sad, i only remember [tag:laravel] has like 2 built-in drivers for flysystem, `local` and `s3`. there are folks out there wrote [tag:smb] driver, not sure whether the package will work with your current version of laravel.